# Accurate Rainfall with TBRG

Tags: meteorology, weather-forecasting

For an accurate flood forecast, up to what height maximum from the ground level one can put the [TBRG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rain_gauge#Tipping_bucket_rain_gauge) without any obstacles and still receive accurate rainfall?

Answer (score 1):

The top of all [rain gauges](http://www.bom.gov.au/climate/cdo/about/rain-measure.shtml) need to be 30 cm above the ground. The lateral placement of all rain gauges is a distance that is twice the height of the nearer tallest item (tree, building, fence, etc.).